# What is causing this bash syntax error?

Tags: bash

This command works fine on the command line...

```
if g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp ; then ./a.out; fi
```

But when I try to adding it to my .bashrc as a function it fails...

```
function cgo() { if g++ -std=c++11 "$1" ; then ./a.out; fi }

>$ cgo main.cpp
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `main.cpp'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: At first these solutions did not work for me but then I tried opening a new terminal and they did. Now I guess the mystery is why the command ". ~/.bashrc" is failing to reload my bashrc in my original terminal session!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `{ braces }` you need to have a newline or semi-colon before the close brace. For one-liners, that means you need a semi-colon

```
function cgo() { if g++ -std=c++11 "$1" ; then ./a.out; fi; }
# ........................................................^
```

Documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping

Comment: `;` is not required in case of nested compound commands. Examples: `{ if true; then echo hello; fi }` and `for i in {1..3}; do if true; then echo "$i"; fi done` and `{ for i in {1..3}; do :; done }`, compared to `{ echo hello; }` and `for i in {1..3}; do echo "$i"; done` where `;` is mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

`}` isn't special; you need to explicitly terminate the preceding command with a `;` if you put the function definition on one line.

```
function cgo () { if g++ -std=c++11 "$1"; then ./a.out; fi; }
```