# Why semicolon NOT required in these cases?

Tags: bash, shell

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48563451/8868289) puzzled me. "They all wrong!" was my thought, as I had previously omitted semicolon in the same or similar cases as the OP did, and all worked fine.

[Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Compound-Commands) about compound commands seemed to prove those answers are right:

> `{ list; }`
>
> The semicolon (or newline) following list is required.

...it says about grouping commands, and similar thing for loops:

> Note that wherever a ‘;’ appears in the description of a command’s syntax, it may be replaced with one or more newlines.

...and all examples use semicolons.

**But**, in practice you can freely omit semicolon when nesting loops, if, curly braces, etc, in any order. For example:

```
{ if true; then echo; fi }
# no ";" here           ^
for i in {1..3}; do if true; then echo "$i"; fi done
# no ";" here                                  ^
{ while true; do if true; then for i in {1..3}; do { echo "$i"; } done fi done }
# no ";" in these 4 places                                       ^    ^  ^    ^
```

I've tested it on bash 4.1, 4.2, 4.4, and dash 0.5.7, they all work consistently.

**My question is**: is it just an implementation peculiarity and I should not rely on it, or a standardized behavior that is safe to rely on?
(Bash docs seem to say nothing about this case).

Comment: It's more about good practices than the ability to do something. Semicolons improve readability so I would personally always use them.

Answer (score 6):

While writing this question, I found information that seems to answer it.

In "Similar Questions" section there is a [question](/q/21246552) about the opposite case (when "`;`" is required), it has a really nice [answer](/a/21246590), but the only thing that we need from it right now, is the [link to POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04).

> The following words shall be recognized as reserved words:
>
> ```
> !     {     }      case
> do    done  elif   else
> esac  fi    for    if
> in    then  until  while
> ```
>
> This recognition shall only occur when none of the characters is quoted and when the word is used as:
>
> - ...
> - The first word following one of the reserved words other than `case`, `for`, or `in`
> - ...

What this states is that constructs like `} done fi done }` are fully legal in POSIX, and all reserved words must be recognized correctly.